# SQL SERVER- Lookup a derived column in another table and return a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which has a column (PROCESS) which was obtained using a concat function. Now i need to lookup this column in a column which is on another table (Table2) and then return a value from the same table (table 2).

Query:
[image]

My Current output will look like this.
[image]

I have a reference Table like this.

[image]

I need to lookup "Process" (Query Result) in "Type" (the reference Table) and return "Description" (Ref table) in "Process Column".

Final Output should look like this
[image]

I'm unable to figure out how to modify my query to do this. pls help.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do here. Perhaps you should share some more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I just edited my query. sorry for not explaining clearly earlier.

Comment: Please look at the link I posted. The final output is a big help but without an understanding of your tables there is little anybody can do. And posting as text instead of images is a HUGE help. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#join-type).  Join your reference table to your other query based on the concatenated value and you can display the description you are looking for.

```
FROM #Source As s) D INNER JOIN [Reference Table] AS rt ON d.Process = rt.type
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `INNER JOIN` between `Source` and `Reference` tables for your nested query with the *JOIN* condition as in the following  :

```
SELECT ... -- all columns of your queries outer part
(
SELECT s.Date, s.Station, s.worktype, s.tasktype, description as process, ....
  FROM source s
  INNER JOIN reference r on ( concat(s.worktype,s.tasktype) = r.type ) 
 ) D
 GROUP BY D.date, D.station, D.worktype, D.accountno;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60fe7/5)